# Create tree from text file

Tags: java, tree

I have file like:

> x1 root
>   x2 root
>   x3 x1
>   x4 x3

So I need to get:

```
root - x1 - x3 - x4
root - x2
```

Language is Java
So I think I need use recursion, am I right?

***ADDED***
So I tried to do it myself. 
That code is working, but isn't brilliant

```
private void findTree(List<String> lines, String item, GenericTreeNode<String> parent, int i){
    if(i >= lines.size()){
        try{
            findTree(lines, parent.getParent().getData(), parent.getParent(), 0);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            print(tree.toStringWithDepth());
        }
    }
    else if(lines.get(i).split(" ")[1].trim().equals(item)){
        item = lines.get(i).split(" ")[0];
        GenericTreeNode<String> child = new GenericTreeNode<String>(item);
        parent.addChild(child);
        lines.remove(i);
        findTree(lines, item, child, 0);
    }else if(item == "XXXXX"){
        print (tree.toStringWithDepth());
    }else if(i!=(lines.size()-1)){
        findTree(lines, item, parent, i+1);
    }else{
        findTree(lines, parent.getParent().getData(), parent.getParent(), 0);
    }
}
```

'XXXXX' it's root in my tree.

Comment: looks like you need to 1) read 2) search for a location 3) attach.  But actually the answer to your question is no.  Recursion is an option, but not needed.

Comment: I feel like it is not safe to assume that input file well be always perfect. Correct? like `x1 root  \n  x4  x3   \n  x3  x1`  could be a possible file?

Comment: Okay, I added some code

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have to use recursion to solve this problem. You can solve this with an iterative solution

For example, you can use a List of Lists structure. ( having a list created at each found occurrence of root )